# Which of the following ideals is maximal in $\mathbb{Z_{3}}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals

**I need to determine which, if any, of the following ideals in $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]$are maximal:**

$$\mathbf{(2)},\, \mathbf{(x+1)},\, \text{and}\, \mathbf{(x^{2}+x+1)}$$

(i.e., the principal ideals generated by the polynomials $2$, $x+1$, and $x^{2}+x+1$, respectively).

This is my attempt:

- For $(x+1)$:

> $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ is a field, since $3$ is prime. Therefore, $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]$ is an integral domain.
>
> Moreover, since $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ is a field, it is vacuously a unique factorization domain. Therefore, $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]$ is also a unique factorization domain.
>
> Now, for $f = x+1 = x - (-1) = x-2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]$, the content is $C(f) = 1$, which is a unit of $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$. Therefore, $x+1$ is primitive in $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]$, which implies that $x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]$ is an integral domain, $(x+1)$ **is a maximal ideal** of $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$

- For $(x^{2}+x+1)$:

> In $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]$, $g = x^{2}+x+1=(x+2)(x+2)$, so $g$ is not irreducible there. Therefore, since $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]$ is an integral domain, $(x^{2}+x+1)$ is **not maximal** there.

- For $(2)$:

> For $h = 2$, the content $C(h) = 2$, which is a unit of $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$. Hence, $h$ is primitive in $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]$
>
> Any possible factorization of $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ will include $2$, so $2$ is an irreducible element of $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]$, which implies that $(2)$ **is maximal**, since $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]$ is an integral domain.

Is this correct? If not, what can I do to fix them? I'm worried I might be missing some subtlety here as to why a nonzero element $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]$ irreducible implies $(k)$ maximal. I have a theorem that says that such "$k$ in an integral domain $R$ is irreducible if and only if $(k)$ is a maximal ideal in the set of all principal ideals of $R$", but does this necessarily mean that it is a maximal ideal of $R$ period?

Comment: Maximal ideals are proper ideals, $2$ is a unit so $(2)=\Bbb Z_3[x]$, so it fails to be maximal.

Comment: @AdamHughes so is this an example of how I am improperly using that result I referred to, and if so, am I also using it improperly in the other two cases?

Comment: An ideal $I$ is maximal in $\Bbb Z_3[x]$ if and only if $\Bbb 
Z_3[x]/I$ is a field.

Comment: Units are special, in theory you can say basically that irreducible <=> prime so and since $\Bbb Z_3[x]/(2)=\{0\}$ is trivially an integral domain it sort of counts like a prime, even though conventions differ on things like what we call primes. But semantics aside, I think that's where you're having the issue. As a rule, the generally preferred characterization for maximal ideals is "maximal iff quotient is a field." With this, you cannot go wrong.

Comment: Your arguments are all right but for $x+1$ and $2$ they are unnecessarily complicated. For 2 as Adam said, well $2$ is a unit so $(2)$ is not maximal. For $x+1$, note that if $F$ is any field and $a\in F$ then the map $F\hookrightarrow F[x]\twoheadrightarrow F[x]/(x-a)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @Hamed okay... Can you explain what those arrows mean here? I'm assuming you're saying the map from $F$ to $F[x]$ is defined to be $F[x]/(x+a)$?

Comment: Oh, curly arrows usually mean an injective map, here I mean the natural inclusion $F\subset F[x]$. The two-headed arrow means a surjection, here it is the natural quotient map.

Comment: @Hamed I've been trying to show that $\mathbb{Z}_{3}/(x-2) \simeq \mathbb{Z_{3}}$ as per your suggestion. Now, I am having trouble showing that, if I define the evaluation homomorphism $\varphi(f(x))=f(2)$, if $f(x) \in \ker \varphi$, then $f(x) \in (x-2)$. Any suggestions as to how this should proceed? (I am trying to use the First Isomorphism Theorem).

Comment: @Hamed that is $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]/(x-2) \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{3}$. I just noticed my typo above but it has been too long since I posted it for me to correct it.

Comment: Let $I=(x-a)$ and $R=F[x]/I$. Let $\phi: F\to F[x]\to R$ beas I defined it before, i.e. it sends any $b\in F$ to $b+I\in R$. **Injectivity**: Suppose $\phi(b)=0+I$ for some $b\neq 0$, then $b\in I$ which is impossible, since $b$ is a unit and $I\neq R$. So $\phi$ is injective. **Surjectivity**: take any $f(x)\in F[x]$. Note that $f(x)+I=f(a)+I$. So $f(x)+I = \phi(f(a))$. Hence $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Regarding your own idea, you have defined the evaluation map $ev: F[x]\to F$.  Obviously $(x-2)\subset \ker ev$. You want to show the converse. The converse basically means if $f(2)=0$, then $f(x)\in (x-2)$. Prove by induction on degree of $f(x)$. For degree $d=1$ (base of induction), $f(x)=a(x-b)$ with $a\neq 0$ is such that $a(b-2)=0$. This immediately means that $b=2$. On the other hand if $f(x)$ is a non-constant polynomial, then $f(x)=(x-2)g(x)+2(g(x)+c/2)$ with $\deg g<\deg f$. So $f(2)=0$ iff $g(2)+c/2=0$. Then by induction $g(x)+c/2\in (x-2)$ and you're done.

Comment: @Hamed one more thing - $\phi: F \to F[x] \to R$ is a composition, right? it's a composition first of a map taking $F \to F[x]$ and then a map taking $F[x] \to R$? Sorry. I'm just not used to your notation.

Comment: Yes, it's the composition of the inclusion and the quotient homomorphisms.